# How to prevent ServiceStackVS to add ApiResponse attribute on generated DTOs?

Tags: servicestack

How to prevent **ServiceStackVS** to add **ApiResponse** attribute on generated DTOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which attributes are exported by either adding or removing them from the `NativeTypesFeature` plugin, e.g The Swagger API attributes can be removed in `AppHost.Configure()` with:

```
var feature = this.GetPlugin<NativeTypesFeature>();

feature.MetadataTypesConfig.ExportAttributes.RemoveWhere(
    x => x is ApiAttribute || 
         x is ApiMemberAttribute ||
         x is ApiResponseAttribute);
```